# Como consigo contar likes da tabela de relacionamento

Tags: sql, mysqli

#### Necessidade

Selecionar os posts junto com os likes correspondente a cada post. Cosegui selecionar o que eu quero, porem quando eu uso o COUNT da erro veja na primeira img.

#### Dados

As duas tabelas também a de post e a de relacionamento para contar os likes.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Monta a sua estrutura em http://sqlfiddle.com/ e depois me marca que faço o SQL para você. É interessante você mostrar como quer a saida, podes montar no Excel e dar um print aqui

Comment: O erro ao qual você se refere é o `null`?